# How do you change control schemes?

Tags: hyrule-warriors

How do you change control schemes (warriors or zelda mode) in Hyrule Warriors?

Comment: Modes as in Control? Or as in "different game types"?

Comment: Yeah, "Zelda" and "Warriors" are the names of the 2 control schemes.

Answer (score 2):

From the main menu, go to **Settings** > **Controller Settings*** > **Button Settings**. This is where you can choose between Warriors Style and Zelda Style.

All this does is change the binding of the four main buttons.

**Warriors:**

- X: Combo Attacks
- A: Special Attack
- B: Dodge
- Y: Regular Attacks

**Zelda:**

- X: Special Attack
- A: Dodge
- B: Regular Attacks
- Y: Combo Attacks

<sub>* this is called "Control Settings" in the 3DS version.</sub>